# See in the shell wehen user registers

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-session, shell

i would like to run a command window which monitors the user registration.
But i do not find the correct command to display that.
So how can i see in command window each time a user registers, logs in and out?

Comment: are u create log file to moniter the user registration

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to get this done, without editing the core, is by creating your own extension. In this extension, you should create three observers: for registration (customer_register_success), login (customer_login) and logout (customer_logout).

In the observers, you can add stuff to the log, like this:

```
<?php

class Namespace_Customer_Model_Observer 
{
    public function trackCustomerRegistration(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
    {
        /** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer */
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

        Mage::log('Customer with email address "' . $customer->getEmail() . '" has registered', 0, 'customer.log');
    }

    public function trackCustomerLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
    {
        /** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer */
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

        Mage::log('Customer with email address "' . $customer->getEmail() . '" has logged in', 0, 'customer.log');
    }

    public function trackCustomerLogout(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
    {
        /** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer */
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

        Mage::log('Customer with email address "' . $customer->getEmail() . '" has logged out', 0, 'customer.log');
    }
}
```

Now that you have the code, you could open your terminal, go to your project's root and execute the following command:

```
tail -f var/log/customer.log
```

This way, all new entries within the log will be shown when they happen.

Answer (score 0):

u can enable log from magento admin and create seperate logs for that use `Mage::log('write something',null,'customerlogfile.log')`